# use boolean list as mask

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this piece of code where I have a list of booleans (named `comb`) and some objects in another list (`self.parents`, always of the same size) that I want to act accordingly on.

This is the current code:

```
    # this is for the result
    parents_arr = []
    # 'comb' is an array of booleans - same size as 'self.parents'
    for i in range(len(comb)):
        # this decides how to act according to comb[i]
        if comb[i]:
            # add string from parent as is to list
            parents_arr.extend([self.parents[i].obj_dict['self'].get_topic()])
        else:
            # append 'not' to string from parent and addto list
            parents_arr.extend(["not %s" % self.parents[i].obj_dict['self'].get_topic()])
```

What it does is, according to the "mask" (the boolean array), it prefixes a "not" string to the ones who are false. I'm convinced there is a cleaner way to do this in python.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fancy trick to get it really short:

```
["not " * (1 - x) + y.obj_dict['self'].get_topic() for x,y in zip(comb, self.parents)]
```

Comment: You probably want `x[1].` instead of just `x.`.

Comment: do you mean `self.parents` in the zip? like so:`zip(comb, self.parents)`

Comment: @pkacprzak Thanks, that's probably what I was looking for to make my TA not examine this code :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani: Don't actually use `'not ' * (1 - x[0])`.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: Because it's unreadable. If you insist on throwing readability out of the window, at least do `'not ' * (not x[0])`. Shorter code isn't necessarily better code.

Comment: I think the readable way to do it is what I had initially, more or less... I can make use of an unreadable one-liner here :-)

Comment: @Blender yes, maybe `not x[0]` is more pythonic, but in terms of a readability I think they are similar.

Comment: What's the benefit of being one line here instead of two? Especially if you have to scroll horizontally to read that one line on a terminal, or on Stack Overflow? If it's really that important, it's trivial to turn BartoszKP's answer into a one-liner just by substituting the one expression into the middle of the other, and it would still be more readable.

Comment: @abarnert it's long only because of `.obj_dict['self'].get_topic()`, I didn't say that there is any benefit. I think that the solution is pretty clean.

Comment: @pkacprzak: The OP who seems to think that your code is unreadable, and yet still a good idea, so the comment is more for him than for you. A readable two-liner is usually a better idea than an unreadable one-liner.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with list comprehension:

```
topics = (x.obj_dict['self'].get_topic() for x in self.parents)
result = [x if y else "not %s" % x for x,y in zip(topics, comb)]
```

Comment: If you never need `topics` except for this `zip`, I'd make it a genexprs instead of a listcomp. But otherwise, nicely readable and still concise.